# How to get the certificate details for the current logged in session of linux server in SSH certificate based authenticaiton?

Tags: ssh, certificate-authority

I am using Certificate based authentication for SSH server access.
I need to get the certificate details of the current logged-in session.
How to do it without grepping into /var/log/secure file?
Need a linux command for it.

I tried
`grep "sshd.* Accepted publickey.* ID" /var/log/secure | tail -n 1`

but i need a direct command which will display the current logged-in session's certificate KEY ID